# Having an error about 'for loop' on python

Tags: python, list, range

I want to make a pattern about finding perfect number.
This number is; the sum of its divisors must be equal to itself
Actually I don't know what is exact problem about. On line 9 it shows my code as wrong.

```
sayi = int(input("enter a number: "))

bolenler = list()
bolenler = range(0,sayi-1)
bolensayi = list()
toplam = 0

for i in bolenler:
    if(sayi % i == 0):
        bolensayi.append(i)

for i in bolensayi:
    toplam += i

if(toplam == sayi):
    print("that number is a perfect number")
else:
    print("that number is not a perfect number")
```

giving that error:

```
sayınızı giriniz: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cagan/Desktop/Python Scratch/mükemmelSayi.py", line 9, in <module>
    if(sayi % i == 0):
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What will be the first value of `i`?

Comment: the first element of `bolenler` is 0, and the module operator is not defined for 0

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are getting that error is because you cannot divide or modulo a number by zero in python. That error is fixed like so:

```
sayi = int(input("enter a number: "))

bolenler = list()
bolenler = range(1,sayi-1)
bolensayi = list()
toplam = 0

for i in bolenler:
    if(sayi % i == 0):
        bolensayi.append(i)

for i in bolensayi:
    toplam += i

if(toplam == sayi):
    print("that number is a perfect number")
else:
    print("that number is not a perfect number")
```

All I did was change the value of `bolenler` from `range(0,sayi-1)` to `range(1,sayi-1)`

You can also make your code a lot shorter like so:

```
sayi = int(input("enter a number: "))
toplam = sum([i for i in range(1, sayi-1) if sayi % i == 0])

if(toplam == sayi):
    print("that number is a perfect number")
else:
    print("that number is not a perfect number")
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError), you can't have the second argument as 0. the variable `bolenler` that you're looping over begins with 0. Initiating the variable as `bolenler = range(1,sayi-1)` should fix it.